# text inside a vbox disappearing in the page

Tags: page, box

I am using the below `vbox` I want to insert a large amount of text , unfortunately the text does not continue to next page. For example, If the text length is 20 lines , only the first 10 lines appear til the end of the page and then the rest of text disappears. I want the text to continue to next page normally.  How can I solve this issue?

```
\newcommand\bioname{\NINE Biographical notes:}
\newbox\t@bio
\def\bio{\@ifnextchar[{\@bio}{\@bio[]}}
\def\@bio[#1]{%
 \global\setbox\t@bio=\vbox\bgroup%
    \parindent10pt\leftskip 10.75pc%\rightskip 3pc%
    \noindent{\bf\TEN \bioname}\ %\vskip 12.8pt
    \noindent\NINE%
    \ignorespaces}%
\def\endbio{\egroup}
```

Comment: The whole point of a box is that it forms an unbreakable unit, if you want it to pagebreak what is the intention of the vbox?

Comment: Pleas e provide a test document that shows the issue, what are `\NINE` and `\TEN` also `\bf` is not defined by default in latex. Also how do you use this command? `#1` is apparently always discarded and not used?

Comment: Thanks for replying,

\def\NINE{\fontsize{9}{10}\selectfont}
\def\TEN{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont}
\bf transforms to bold

Comment: I am using a template, this template has default settings to add this text, in my case this text is large I want to break it to the next page.

Comment: By default `\bf` does not transform to bold, it is undefined. Some classes define it for compatibility with documents written for latex2.09 before 1993, so it shouldn't be used now. but please do not add code in comments, fix your example so that people can run it and see the issue.  But you did not say what you want the vbox to do, normally a vbox is used specifically to prevent page breaks.

Comment: how to overcome the vbox that does not allow page break to be able to add my text to it ??

Comment: I am sorry but you have not said what you want this code to do or given any indication of how it is used. The only thing that fragment does is set up an environment that throws away its argument and saves its content in a box but does not use it, so if you don't use a box there it is equivalent to doing nothing at all. Presumably you have some other code using the box and perhaps that code can be changed not to use a box, but how can we know what it is?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/vWsYtkyC
this link contains link for the code

Comment: please don't use external links, make a self contained example in your question that shows the issue.